Кастомные параметры шаблона Visual Studio
В VS при создании шаблонов проекта, к примеру web api, можно настроить различные параметры, которые тем или иным образом влияют на структуру проекта.
Как реализовать этот функционал для своего шаблона. К примеру чекбокс для подключения бд (Использовать или нет) или выпадающий список типа Id (Guid, string или int) у сущностей.

Искать где-то здесь: Create custom project and item templates, Create project templates
